# Can a Python function take a generator and return generators to subsets of its generated output?

Tags: python, generator

Let's say I have a generator function like this:

```
import random
def big_gen():
  i = 0
  group = 'a'
  while group != 'd':
    i += 1
    yield (group, i)
    if random.random() < 0.20:
      group = chr(ord(group) + 1)
```

Example output might be:
('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('a', 4), ('a', 5), ('a', 6), ('a', 7), ('a', 8), ('b', 9), ('c', 10), ('c', 11), ('c', 12), ('c', 13)

I would like to break this into three groups: Group A, Group B, and Group C. And I would like a generator for each group. Then I'd pass the generator and the group letter into a  subfunction. An example of the subfunction:

```
def printer(group_letter, generator):
  print "These numbers are in group %s:" % group_letter
  for num in generator:
    print "\t%s" % num
```

The desired output would be:

```
These numbers are in group a:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
These numbers are in group b:
9
These numbers are in group c:
10
11
12
13
```

How can I do this without changing big_gen() or printer(), and avoid storing the entire group in memory at once? (In real life, the groups are **huge**)

Comment: In real life, is it OK to walk the big generator several times? Or does the data get consumed in some irrevocable way? If I understand your example correctly, the state for the call to random() doesn't get stored anywhere useful so you can't walk that generator again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, this does what you want:

```
import itertools
import operator

def main():
  for let, gen in itertools.groupby(big_gen(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    secgen = itertools.imap(operator.itemgetter(1), gen)
    printer(let, secgen)
```

`groupby` does the bulk of the work here -- the `key=` just tells it what field to group by.

The resulting generator needs to be wrapped in an `imap` just because you've specified your `printer` signature to take an iterator over number, while, by nature, `groupby` returns iterators over the same items it gets as its input -- here, 2-items tuples with a letter followed by a number -- but this is not really all that germane to your question's title.

The answer to that title is that, yep, a Python function can perfectly well do the job you want -- `itertools.groupby` in fact does exactly that. I recommend studying the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module carefully, it's a very useful tool (and delivers splendid performance as well).

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight problem here. You'd like the function to printer() to take a generator for each group, but in reality you have the same generator yielding all groups. You have two options, as I see it:

1) Change big_gen() to yield generators:

```
import random
def big_gen():
  i = 0
  group = 'a'
  while group != 'd':
    def gen():
        i += 1
        yield i
        if random.random() < 0.20:
            group = chr(ord(group) + 1)
    yield group, gen

 from itertools import imap
 imap(lambda a: printer(*a), big_gen())
```

2) Change printer() to keep state and notice when the group changes (keeping your original big_gen() function):

```
def printer(generator):
  group = None
  for grp, num in generator:
    if grp != group:
        print "These numbers are in group %s:" % grp
        group = grp
    print "\t%s" % num
```